# Refresh-button UIProgressBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I implemented a UIProgressBar into my WebView to show the duration for loading. Everything works but I would like to know how I can add a refresh-button for the UIWebView with the UIProgressBar. The UIProgressBar should appear each time I click on the refresh-button, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't get incremental progress for webview loading, the webview delegate will only tell you when it starts and when it finishes.

You could fake it by estimating the time it will take and just increasing the progress bar with a timer - sometimes the appearance of progress is better than nothing.

But I'd suggest using a UIActivityView instead, which provides indication of activity without the explicit progress value.

To use a UIActivity view, just show it in the webview's didStartLoad delegate method and hide it in the didFinishLoad. Don't forget to handle errors like didFailLoadWithError as well.

Comment: No that's not what I wanted. Because it's a pdf I wanted to show it with a uiprogressbar. And it's working! The only question I have is how to make a refreshbutton...

Comment: Oh, I see. Well what of you just add a UIButton that calls [webview reload]? Or what if you put the loading code from your viewDidLoad in its own method and just call it again?

Comment: Thanks I made an own method and it loads it again, because [aWebView reload] doesn't work. But now it loads from 100% to 200%. And if I click on the refresh-button again it loads from 200% to 300%. Seems like I made something wrong... Any ideas?

Comment: You need to reset all of these properties back to zero before each time you load: int totalfilesize;
    int filesizereceived;
    float filepercentage;